# Exclude already-viewed questions from Answer Similar Questions

Tags: feature-request, answer-similar-questions

I was offered questions I had already interacted with (upvoted a comment IIRC).  The feature would feel slightly less annoying if it suggested stuff I have actually missed or ignored.

(Also, maybe it would be less annoying if it presented those suggestions right away, instead of had me click a button like I was new with this mouse and keyboard stuff.)